# I want to create customized an android birthday wish app

Tags: android

I want to create customized an android app that include of a birthday wish for my girl friend. That speak alert something or message alert something when 12 am in her birthday? How can I do this?

Comment: What code have you tried so far for your girl friend ? ;)

Comment: grt8 idea u can go for Text to speech Class Availabe in android>Sample>Apidemos

Answer (score 2):

Use `AlarmManager` to fire off given `Intent` on specified date and time. Then use `BroadcastReceiver` to catch that `Intent` and perform whatever you like.